# How to render photo from camera roll within a card

Tags: react-native

I want to render my camera roll as a stack of cards. I've used a library called swiper to accomplish the stack of cards, and within it am rendering the cards. I've created a function that gets the photos and stores them in an array. I'm just confused as to how I will render each of these images within a card.

Code:

```
export default function App() {

  state = {
    photoArray: []
  }

  function getPhotosFromGallery() {
    CameraRoll.getPhotos({ first: 1000000 })
      .then(res => {
        let photoArray = res.edges;
        this.setState({ showPhotoGallery: true, photoArray: photoArray })
      })
  }

  const swiperRef = React.useRef();

  const [index,setIndex] = React.useState(0);

  const onSwiped = () => {
    setIndex(index + 1)
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header
        leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#fff' }}
        centerComponent={{ text: 'MY TITLE', style: { color: '#fff' } }}
        rightComponent={{ icon: 'home', color: '#fff' }}
      />
      <View style = {styles.swiperContainer}>
        <Swiper
          cards={['exampleCard','exampleCard','exampleCard','exampleCard','exampleCard']}
            renderCard={(card) => {
              return (
                <View style={styles.card}>
                  <Card>
                    <CardTitle
                    title = {card}
                    />

                    //Camera Roll images would be rendered here

                  </Card>
                </View>
              )
            }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<Swiper
  cards={this.state.photoArray}
  renderCard={(card,index) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.card}>

        <Card>
          <CardTitle
            title={card}
          />
          <Image
            loadingStyle={{ size: 'large', color: 'white' }}
            style={{ height: width, width: width }}
            placeholderStyle={{
              height: width,
              width: width
            }}
            defaultSource={placeHolderImage}
            placeholderSource={placeHolderImage}
            source={{ uri: Image_URL }}
          />
        </Card>
      </View>
    )
  }}>
</Swiper>
```

Comment: I've attempted to use card.node.image.uri as the source of the uri in hopes of iterating through all my images but I get the error card.node is not an object. How can I refer to the uri?

Comment: Can you please show in which formate you have data in `photoArray`?

Comment: Yes it's an edge or array of node objects containing the images and the URI. Further information is here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/cameraroll.html. If you look at getPhotos() you can see the data I'm using and it's properties

Comment: Yes, you have used correct formate. Can you print console log before doing in setState()?

Comment: I've added the line "console.log(res, "images data")" in setState() and it doesn't produce any errors. I'm using expo and am not sure where the console log is written though.

Comment: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/logging/ for log

Comment: I am getting "CameraRoll" is not defined. Online it's saying this is due to not linking properly. For iOS permissions I have added "NSCameraUsageDescription" and "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription" to the app.json so I'm not sure why it isn't linking properly. This need for permissions is referred to in the beginning of the link I sent earlier (camera roll docs).

Comment: I will suggest you check `CameraRoll` import statement.

Comment: You're right I didn't realize they removed camera roll from react native so I had to import it from react-native-community. I'm getting cannot read property getPhotos of undefined. I believe this is a linking issue but I've added everything to the app.json so I'm not sure what's left to link it

Comment: Check this link https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cameraroll/issues/128#issuecomment-576189437